# I am scraping an amazon website using selenium for product links But got the error attached below

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping

Below is my code for scraping product links from amazon but getting the error. I am trying for scraping links from multiple pages the code is fine and work right for 3 pages after that give the below mentioned error.

```
wbD = wb.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
wbD.get('https://www.amazon.com/s?i=specialty-aps&bbn=16225007011&rh=n%3A16225007011%2Cn%3A193870011&ref=nav_em__nav_desktop_sa_intl_computer_components_0_2_6_3')
links = []
condition = True
while condition:
    
    productlist = wbD.find_elements_by_class_name('a-size-mini')
    for elem in productlist:
        if(elem.text !='' and elem.text !='Sponsored'):
            pp2 = elem.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
            links.append(pp2.get_property('href'))
    try:
        wbD.find_element_by_class_name('a-last').find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_property('href')
        wbD.find_element_by_class_name('a-last').click()
    except:
        condition = False

print(links)
```

[Getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTpDx.png)

Answer (score 1):

Oddly the tag_name was messing up and I added time.sleep() for any max retry errors.

```
while True:
    productlist = WebDriverWait(wbD, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "a-size-mini")))
    for elem in productlist:
        if(elem.text !='' and elem.text !='Sponsored'):
            pp2 = elem.find_element_by_xpath('//a')
            links.append(pp2.get_property('href'))
    try:
        wbD.find_element_by_class_name('a-last').find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_property('href')
        wbD.find_element_by_class_name('a-last').click()
        
    except:
        break
    time.sleep(5)

print(links)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be caused by page is still not loaded or just because no such element (a) in these product, you may need append an exception while such element by tag name: a

```
 links = []
 condition = True
 while condition:

productlist = wbD.find_elements_by_class_name("a-size-mini")
for elem in productlist:
    if(elem.text !="" and elem.text !="Sponsored"):
        try:
          pp2 = elem.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
          links.append(pp2.get_property('href'))
        except Exception as e:
          print('Error', e)
        
try:
    wbD.find_element_by_class_name('a-last').find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_property('href')
    wbD.find_element_by_class_name('a-last').click()
except:
    condition = False

print(links)
```

Comment: Element (a) and the product is available. If there is a problem of not loading a page waht should i do?